# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS netboot

Tags: cd-image

Where can I get a netboot cd image for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS? I only get the beta version from here http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/18.04/ and some other places.

Answer (score 5):

Go to http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/, then

- For 64-bit: navigate to installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/
- For 32-bit: navigate to installer-i386/current/images/netboot/

Get the network-based installer `mini.iso`.

Alternatively, go to [Ubuntu.com](https://www.ubuntu.com), then choose Downloads > [Alternative downloads](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads) and get the network installer.

Comment: I think this is the same as http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/18.04/ ?

Comment: @Mr.Openk: Yes, the network installer link from the alternative downloads points to [cdimage.ubuntu.com](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/18.04/). The point is that these are the official distribution points; in particular [archive.ubuntu.com](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/) is where `apt-get` on Ubuntu gets its packages. The "Beta" in the title of the page is misleading.

Comment: I have installed it and it is true lts version. Thanks :)

Comment: I have quiestion! Can I add For 64-bit: navigate to installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/ to my localrepo? I can not add it in sources.list

Comment: @imurD: It's not a package repository. It's a plain directory where you can find am ISO file containing the boot image. You are supposed to use it to make installation media (USB drive or CD-ROM), and boot from it.